# Curl, SSL e Segurança

Tags: php, libcurl, ssl

Olá

Tenho uma pequena dúvida quanto ao CURL e SSL.

Tenho visto que é inseguro colocar false em CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, pois faria o CURL não verificar o SSL, possibilitando interceptação de dados.

Porém não entendi como isso poderia ocorrer. Por exemplo, tenho um script em um servidor que acessa outro servidor via https. Para alguém interceptar isso, ele necessitaria estar na mesma rede física do servidor onde meu script está hospedado, não? Se não, como se explicaria tal insegurança?

Obrigado

Comment: É possível sim, por isso que é recomendado o uso de criptografia para a transmissão de informações importantes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que esteja se conectando com um servidor HTTPS e define o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` para `false` você se torna vulnerável a ataques de [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), inclusive algumas bibliotecas já possuíram problemas com isso no passado, como por exemplo o [Google AdWords PHP Client](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/2b7ee485a24b6757e5cca07ea17301e015e5f181/build_lib/WSDLInterpreter/WSDLInterpreter.php#L341-L360), uma vez que o `stream_context_get_default()` no PHP 5.6 e inferior não verificava os certificados eram emitidos por uma autoridade confiável (*self-signed era válido*), assim tornando vulnerável a conexões que não são reais da Google.

Em geral NUNCA desligue esta verificação.

Ter os dados transmitidos de maneira criptografadas não faz ser seguro, só será seguro se você garantir que o receptor da informação é realmente quem diz ser. Isso somente será possível se você definir o `CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY` (disponível no PHP 7.0.7+) este é o mais seguro dos métodos. Uma outra opção e mais versátil é confiar em um autoridade (ex. Comodo) e então utilizar o `CURLOPT_CAINFO` para determinar quais autoridades são confiáveis para você e o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` para `true` para verificar se o certificado foi emitido por alguém que você confia.

---

Caso não utilize o `VERIFYPEER` você está vulnerável para:

- DNS Poisoning
- Spoofing
- Proxy Attacks
- ARP Spoofing

***etc...***

---

O SSL sem utilizar o `VERIFYPEER` o máximo que pode ocorrer é a informação ser trafegada de maneira criptografada, mas não garante que o destino da sua  conexão é real, *o que anula parcialmente o proposito do SSL*.

Imagine deseja se conectar com o `https://google.com`, então você precisa de um DNS que encontre o real *host* do `google.com`. O DNS é atacado e lhe envia para o `1.1.1.1`. Este `1.1.1.1` utiliza um certificado `self-signed` com o nome de  `google.com`, o seu CURL irá se conectar nele normalmente. Então este falso servidor terá como obter as informações que você enviaria para o `google.com` e para você não desconfiar ele faz um *proxying* para o *real* google.com, retornando resultados verdadeiros. Agora o servidor intermediário (`1.1.1.1`) tem as informações que você enviou e as resposta reais do `google.com`.

Do que adiantou ter o tráfego criptografado? Nada.

*Se você desligar o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` o certificado pode até ser de `abc.com` e está se conectando em `xyz.com` e será válido.*

---

A "interceptação de dados" não vai ocorrer porque parou de usar o SSL! Vai ocorrer porque não necessariamente está se conectando com o servidor real, devido a não verificação do certificado.

---

**Não precisa confiar em mim, palavras do próprio CURL:**

> WARNING: disabling verification of the certificate allows bad guys to
>   man-in-the-middle the communication without you knowing it. Disabling
>   verification makes the communication insecure. Just having encryption
>   on a transfer is not enough as you cannot be sure that you are
>   communicating with the correct end-point.

Comment: Agora eu entendi.... Obrigado pela explicação

Answer (score 2):

Colocar "false" não torna nada inseguro, pois conexão ainda será SSL e criptografada. Você só não pode colocar false se estiver fazendo isso em um serviço ou link que necessita de certificados com validação, pois nesse caso, você receberia muitas queixas sobre não estar podendo fazer a autenticidade do certificado no site. Neste caso, é necessário este segurança, para evitar códigos maliciosos que assume a identidade da "microsoft.com" e que começa a criar hosts próprios de Windows Update, que podem ameaçar e comprometer a integridade do servidor, podendo enviar vírus ou abrir portas através de chaves que se instalam ou scripts maliciosos. Independentemente de qualquer configuração que você faça nisso, se você forçar uma conexão SSL, ela será segura e criptografada. Resumindo, colocar "true" só se faz necessário, se houver requisição de certificados, pois daí tem entrada de dados, aí existem perigos.

**[Aqui tem mais detalhes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660610/if-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-is-false-is-the-data-transfer-no-longer-secure)**, se entender inglês.

Comment: Quando você diz entrada de dados, refere-se por exemplo ao envio de algum texto específico nessa chamada CURL?