# CURL utilizando PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Eu tenho esse comando no cmd do Windows:

```
C:\Users\Jhon\Desktop>curl -k -u username:senha https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/api/3.0/generateflawreport.do -F "app_id_list=000000" -F "scan_type=static"
```

Gostaria de obter os resultados, importando para o PHP, mas não sei como fazer.

Por favor, alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Comece estudando PHP; posteriormente estudando a biblioteca cURL nativa nela. Após isso terá condições de tentar fazer sozinho e, se não conseguir, poderá [edit] sua pergunta com maiores detalhes da sua tentativa. Sem isso, sua pergunta se aproxima muito a uma pergunta do tipo "façam para mim", o que não é bem recebido pela comunidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode ver na documentação o que é equivalente para cada comando:

> curl -k -u username:senha https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/api/3.0/generateflawreport.do -F "app_id_list=000000" -F "scan_type=static

---

> **-k** [*(Não é recomendado usar)*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187032/15089)

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER (definido para FALSE)
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST (definido para FALSE)
```

> **-u**

```
CURLOPT_USERPWD
```

> **-f**

```
CURLOPT_POST
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS (usando array para multipart/form-data)
```

---

No final terá algo como:

```
// URL:
$ch = curl_init('https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/api/3.0/generateflawreport.do');

// Obter retorno em $resultado:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// -F
// Definir como POST:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// -F
// Definir corpo, como multipart/form-data:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['app_id_list' => '000000','scan_type' => 'static']);

// -u
// Definir o usuário/senha do HTTP Basic Authentication:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username'.':'.'senha');

// -k
// Desligar a verificação do TLS (não é recomendado usar isto para FALSE!):
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);


$resultado = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

// Visualizar resultado:
var_dump($resultado);
```

Você pode ver em detalhes as funções em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php, nesta página terá todos os `CURLOPT_*` que pode utilizar. Alguns podem estar faltando, então consulte também o https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html para maiores detalhes sobre cada comando. Lembre-se de atualizar o cURL para a ultima versão, assim poderá usar todos os recursos.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Inkeliz, funcionou perfeitamente.
Muito agradecido pela ajuda.
abs